# If we consider Q (rational numbers) the binary operation on this set are?

Tags: binary-operations

I know addition, multiplication and subtraction are definitely defined.

However division does not work on this set because if a = some integer and b = 0 then a/b is not in the rational numbers.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Division is a binary operation on $\mathbb{Q} ^*$ however.

Comment: One can define infinitely many such operations, of course. Is the question about the commonly used operations with widely accepted names?